# Can't convert numbers from file to double format

Tags: java, string, file, double

I need to convert numbers (splitting with spaces) from file (*.txt) to double format.

File contains the line of double format numbers like "3.50 3.51 -3.49 -3.50 -3.51". But this code throws ParseException "Unparseable number: "﻿3.50" " and I can't get why is it happening? I've try to do the same with Double.parseDouble and .valueOf, but it always throws an Exception.

I'm interested in the cause of exception, not in another ways of solving this task. Could anyone explain it to me, please?

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Scanner fileI = new Scanner(new File(reader.readLine()));
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();

    while(fileI.hasNextLine())
    {
        String[] str = fileI.nextLine().split(" ");
        for (String it: str)
        {
            System.out.println(nf.parse(it).doubleValue());
        }
    }
    fileI.close();
```

Comment: I am not getting the error you describe. Your code works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Most likely this is due to your locale - some countries require a comma for the decimal separator. Try the version of [`getInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getInstance(java.util.Locale)) that requires a [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) parameter. You can provide something like `Locale.US`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Double.parseDouble(String s)`

If it is not what you want, try to do something like

```
for (String it: str)
{
    try{
        System.out.println(nf.parse(it).doubleValue());
    }catch (ParseException e){
        System.out.println("unappeasable number - "+it);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is really helpful!

Comment: @Al-Phantom but that was not really the answer to your question was it? Remember you said that you were not "interested in another ways in solving this task". I seriously feel bad flagging another user with a similar answer if you don't stick to your guns ...

Comment: @JoD. Yes, I still don't get why it throws an exception (I found with try-catch it happens only with the first string of array). Using Locale parameter doesn't helps, and the same with using commas. I should be going to read documentation thoroughly I guess.

Comment: @JoD. I found a reason of exception.  It happened because of file. I was trying to do the same with FileInputStream and found that there was extra bytes at the begining of file. Notepad put it to indicate that the file was saved in the UTF-8 encoding.